# How to make parts of a website under SSL and the rest not?

Tags: python, ssl, cherrypy

I need to create a cherrypy main page that has a login area.  I want the login area to be secure, but not the rest of the page.  How can I do this in CherryPy?

Ideally, any suggestions will be compatible with http://web.archive.org/web/20170210040849/http://tools.cherrypy.org:80/wiki/AuthenticationAndAccessRestrictions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only want parts of the actual *page* to be secure, you should create an iframe pointing to a HTTPS source. However, this shows a *"secure and non-secure items on page"* warning to the user.

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly considered a bad idea.  The primary reason is that it confuses most people due to the website identity markers appearing in just about every current browsers url area.